# Chat using rust-websocket

Tags: websocket, rust, chat

I'm trying to use Rust-Websocket to create a simple chatroom where multiple people can talk to each other.

I looked at the examples and the 'server.rs' and 'websockets.html' looked like a decent starting point to me. So I just tried starting it up and connecting from web. Everything works but I can only communicate with myself and not with other connections (since it sends the message back directly to `sender` and not to every connection).

So I'm trying to get a vector with all `senders`/`clients` so I can just iterate through them and send the message to each one but this seems to be problematic. I cannot communicate the `sender` or `client` since It's not thread safe and I cannot copy any of these either.

I'm not sure if I just don't understand the whole borrowing 100% or if it's not intended to do cross-connection communication like this.

server.rs:
https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/examples/server.rs

websockets.html:
https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/examples/websockets.html

I might be approaching this from the wrong direction. It might be easier to share a received message with all other threads. I thought about this a little bit but the only thing I can think of is sending a message from inside a thread to outside using `channels`. Is there any way to broadcast messages directly between the threads? All I would need to do is send a string from one thread to the other.

Comment: I tried something similar and gave up. AFAICS the problem is that the receiver object doesn't have a method named `try_recv_message`. This means that when you start looking for a message the server will block until you have actually received a message.

https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/2f80d4c4889602d63cc745aa18e3fdd4ae71eb8a/src/ws/receiver.rs

The project named rust-chat uses a different websocket library, and they work around it by using multicasting.

https://github.com/nbaksalyar/rust-chat/blob/master/src/main.rs

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. But I can't believe this would be so hard with rust-websocket since even their example is using a web chat. It looked to me like they intended for the user to expand on their example since a single client chat doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It is very possible that I missed something. Please post if you find a solution.

Comment: Include an [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem, emphasis on the **Minimal**. Otherwise, you are basically asking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Btw nielsle I've looked at your link and I've read through this guy's instructions a few days ago. The first part looked very promising but the code of his second part does not work and he hasn't uploaded a complete version of it to his github either. Judging by the time between the first two parts this guide will need some time to be really finished. It's still a good read tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not quite as straight-forward as one might think.

Basically I used a dispatcher thread that would act like a control center for all the connected clients. So whenever a client receives a message it's sent to the dispatcher and this then distributes the message to every connected client.

I also had to receive the messages in another thread because there is no non-blocking way to receive messages in rust-websocket. Then I ways able to just use a permanent loop that checks both for new messages received from the websocket and from the dispatcher.

Here's how my code looked like in the end:

```
extern crate websocket;

use std::str;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

use websocket::{Server, Message, Sender, Receiver};
use websocket::header::WebSocketProtocol;
use websocket::message::Type;


fn main() {
    let server = Server::bind("0.0.0.0:2794").unwrap();

    let (dispatcher_tx, dispatcher_rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();
    let client_senders: Arc<Mutex<Vec<mpsc::Sender<String>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));

    // dispatcher thread
    {
        let client_senders = client_senders.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(msg) = dispatcher_rx.recv() {
                for sender in client_senders.lock().unwrap().iter() {
                    sender.send(msg.clone()).unwrap();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // client threads
    for connection in server {
        let dispatcher = dispatcher_tx.clone();
        let (client_tx, client_rx) = mpsc::channel();
        client_senders.lock().unwrap().push(client_tx);

        // Spawn a new thread for each connection.
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let request = connection.unwrap().read_request().unwrap(); // Get the request
            let headers = request.headers.clone(); // Keep the headers so we can check them

            request.validate().unwrap(); // Validate the request

            let mut response = request.accept(); // Form a response

            if let Some(&WebSocketProtocol(ref protocols)) = headers.get() {
                if protocols.contains(&("rust-websocket".to_string())) {
                    // We have a protocol we want to use
                    response.headers.set(WebSocketProtocol(vec!["rust-websocket".to_string()]));
                }
            }

            let mut client = response.send().unwrap(); // Send the response

            let ip = client.get_mut_sender()
                .get_mut()
                .peer_addr()
                .unwrap();

            println!("Connection from {}", ip);

            let message: Message = Message::text("SERVER: Connected.".to_string());
            client.send_message(&message).unwrap();

            let (mut sender, mut receiver) = client.split();

            let(tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Message>();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
                    tx.send(message.unwrap()).unwrap();
                }
            });

            loop {
                if let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv() {
                    match message.opcode {
                        Type::Close => {
                            let message = Message::close();
                            sender.send_message(&message).unwrap();
                            println!("Client {} disconnected", ip);
                            return;
                        },
                        Type::Ping => {
                            let message = Message::pong(message.payload);
                            sender.send_message(&message).unwrap();
                        },
                        _ => {
                            let payload_bytes = &message.payload;
                            let payload_string = match str::from_utf8(payload_bytes) {
                                Ok(v) => v,
                                Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                            };
                            let msg_string = format!("MESSAGE: {}: ", payload_string);
                            dispatcher.send(msg_string).unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if let Ok(message) = client_rx.try_recv() {
                    let message: Message = Message::text(message);
                    sender.send_message(&message).unwrap();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/H9McWLrH

Comment: isnt' the loop for `rx.try_recv()` consuming 100% of your CPU ?